# Failed with exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I use ktor client with Kinopoisk Unofficial API, and it works well and I see a good response from the server in my log, but I can't show data on my screen. Instead of that I get a fatal exception:

> failed with exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input.

I searched the answer on the Internet much time but nothing helps me. The code isn't very clean because I reduce it:

My error:

> I/System.out: BODY Content-Type: application/json
> I/System.out: BODY START
> I/System.out: {"keyword":"матриуа","pagesCount":2,"films":[{"filmId":301,"nameRu":"Матрица","nameEn":"The Matrix","type":"FILM","year":"1999","description":"Жизнь Томаса Андерсона разделена на две части: днём он — самый {"genre":"фантастика"}],"rating":"7.6","ratingVoteCount":227933,"posterUrl":"https‍://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/...
> I/System.out: BODY END
> I/System.out: 21:50:19.215 [main] INFO io.ktor.client.HttpClient - RESPONSE https‍://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech/api/v2.1/films/search-by-keyword?keyword=%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%B0
> failed with exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

My build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'

    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.3.0"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.3.0"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:2.3.0"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:2.3.0"
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    implementation"io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.0"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.3.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0"
}
```

data class

```
@Serializable
data class MoviesContainerData(
    @SerialName("keyword")
    val keyword: String,
    @SerialName("pagesCount")
    val pagesCount: Int,
    @SerialName("films")
    val films: List<MovieInfoData>,
    @SerialName("searchFilmsCountResult")
    val searchFilmsCountResult: Int
)
```

ApiServiceImpl

```
class ApiServiceImpl(
    private val client: HttpClient
) : ApiService {
    override suspend fun getMovies(request: String): List<MovieInfoData> {
        var response: List<MovieInfoData> = listOf()
        try {
            val httpResponse = client.get {
                url {
                    protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
                    host = "kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech"
                    path(END_POINT_SEARCH_BY_KEYWORD)
                    parameters.append(KEYWORD_NAME_KEY, request)

                }
                headers {
                    append(CONTENT_TYPE_KEY_NAME, CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE)
                    append(API_NAME_KEY, API_VALUE)
                }
            }
            Log.d("films", "STATUS: ${httpResponse.status}")
            Log.d("films", "HEADERS: ${httpResponse.headers}")
            val httpClient: List<MovieInfoData> = httpResponse.body<MoviesContainerData>().films
            Log.d("films", "BODY:${httpClient}")

            return emptyList()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("responseFromServer", "ERROR: ${e.message}")
            response = emptyList()
        } 
        return response
    }
```

ApiService

```
interface ApiService {
    suspend fun getMovies(request: String): List<MovieInfoData>

    suspend fun getMovieDetail(filmId: Int): MovieDetailData

    companion object {
        fun create(): ApiService {
            return ApiServiceImpl(
                client = HttpClient(Android) {
                    install(Logging) {
                        level = LogLevel.ALL
                    }
                    install(ContentNegotiation) {
                        json(Json{
                            prettyPrint = true
                            isLenient = true
                            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                        })
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

So I see in Log when I call request in `ApiServiceImpl`, I get a good response, but then I can't do anything with it, even if I call `body()` for this response. So help me!

Comment: You need to look into the cause of the `JsonConvertException` to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `explicitNulls = false`:

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json(
        Json{
            explicitNulls = false
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }
    )
}
```